# How to check if a cursor style is supported

Tags: javascript, css, mouse-cursor

How can I check, with JavaScript, whether `cursor:none` is supported?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply create an element, set the property, and check whether the property is still existent.

```
function isCursorNoneSupported() {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.style.cursor = "none";
    return a.style.cursor === 'none';
}

if ( isCursorNoneSupported() ) {
    alert("cursor:none is supported!");
} else {
    alert("cursor:none is not supported :(");
}
```

To check which browsers support `cursor:none`, have a look at: [`cursor` Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @refhat `===` is an identity operator. In this case, it doesn't matter whether you're using `==` or `===`, because both objects are a string. For more details on `===` vs `==`, see [JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)